# deleting a row in word table if a certain number of cells are empty and/or contain a certain value

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this code (attached below) which will delete the rows in a word table if all the cell rows are empty.

However I have a table with eight columns, the first four of which will always contain text. The latter four contains data linked to an excel document.

The question is; how do I get the code to search through the latter four (data) columns and IF the columns are empty and/or contain a value (such as zero) THEN delete the row.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
    Sub DeleteBlankRowsAndTablesInATable()
  Dim objCell As Cell
  Dim nRowIndex As Integer, nRows As Integer, nColumns As Integer, nColumnIndex As Integer
  Dim varCellEmpty As Boolean
 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
  If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then
    MsgBox ("Put cursor inside a table first!")
    Exit Sub
  Else
    With Selection.Tables(1)
      nRows = .Rows.Count
      For nRowIndex = nRows To 1 Step -1
        varCellEmpty = True
        For Each objCell In .Rows(nRowIndex).Cells
          If Len(objCell.Range.Text) > 2 Then
            varCellEmpty = False
            Exit For
          End If
        Next objCell
          If varCellEmpty = True Then
            .Rows(nRowIndex).Delete
          End If
      Next nRowIndex
 

    End With
  End If

  Set objCell = Nothing

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The following code was used:

```
Sub DeleteBlankRowsAndTablesInATable()
Dim objCell As Range
Dim nRowIndex As Integer, nRows As Integer, nColumns As Integer, nColumnIndex As Integer
Dim varCellEmpty As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then
        MsgBox ("Put cursor inside a table first!")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        With Selection.Tables(1)
            nRows = .Rows.Count
            For nRowIndex = nRows To 1 Step -1
                varCellEmpty = True
                For nColumns = 5 To .Columns.Count
                    Set objCell = .Rows(nRowIndex).Cells(nColumns).Range
                    objCell.End = objCell.End - 1
                    If Len(objCell) > 0 And Not objCell.Text = "0" Then
                        varCellEmpty = False
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next nColumns
                If varCellEmpty = True Then .Rows(nRowIndex).Delete
            Next nRowIndex
        End With
    End If
    Set objCell = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```